# Can we type if statement inside the function an argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

**For example**

```
def person(name,if age == 18:...//some instructions and this parameter will be default parameter):
   print(age)
   print(name)

person('Ratheesh')
```

// I Know it sounds dump and silly, but is there any possibility to do that?

I was trying to confirm the user has entered the exact value in argument as i entered...But fortunately i have done it with default argument but whenever i change the parameter value it overrides so, i want to avoid the override...

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. But you can make that statement the first line of your function. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Samwise Yes i tried..it says synax error

Comment: @DYZ I was trying to confirm the user has entered the exact value in argument as i entered...But fortunately i have done it with default argument but whenever i change the argument's value it overrides so, i want to avoid the override...

Answer (score 1):

You can technically have an `if` inside the expression where you define a function's default argument, but note that the expression will be evaluated *when the function is defined*:

```
>>> default = "drinking age"
>>> def person(name: str, age: int = 21 if default == "drinking age" else 18):
...     print(name, age)
...
>>> person("Bob")
Bob 21
>>> default = "voting age"
>>> person("Bob")
Bob 21
```

For practical purposes it's hard to imagine why you'd ever want to do something like this.  It'd make more sense to do that evaluation inside the body of the function:

```
>>> def person(name: str, age: Optional[int] = None):
...     if age is None:
...         age = 21 if default == "drinking age" else 18
...     print(name, age)
...
>>> person("Bob")
Bob 18
>>> default = "drinking age"
>>> person("Bob")
Bob 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a default parameter?

```
def person(name, age=18):
   print(age)
   print(name)

person('Ratheesh')
```

Returns:

```
18
Ratheesh
```

And:

```
person('Ratheesh', 20)
```

Returns:

```
20
Ratheesh
```

Comment: Well, what if i change age's value which means 21..it overrides and print 21. So I want to avoid the overriding thing..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the `if` condition as a parameter. Whatever you are trying to achieve can be done using the `if` condition inside the code as below :

```
def person(name,age):
   if age == 18:
       #some instructions 
   print(age)
   print(name)

person('Ratheesh',10)
```

To answer your question, **NO**, you cannot pass an if condition as an argument. Maybe you can refer the below code if you are trying to put a default parameter value :

```
def person(name,age=18): #this will set the default value of age to 18 in case it isn't mention in the call
   if age == 18:
       #some instructions 
   print(age)
   print(name)

person('Ratheesh')
```

Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: Yes i already know that but whenever i change age's value, it overrides. So,I want to avoid that overriding...

Comment: I didn't get your doubt exactly. What about overriding?

Comment: For example : The default value of age is 18. Suppose if i change the value of age as 21 it prints 21 . I want to avoid that value is changing

Comment: You could use another variable to store age value and print it later. what exactly are you doing inside the `if()` statement ?

Comment: i don't know what to do inside the if()statement ,but i want confirm that value inside argument not changed whenever i pass another value on it

Comment: @RatheeshKanthRavichandran You can use another temporary variable to store the value of the original age so you will have the original value with you for later use as well